# How to upgrade my Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 15.04

I currently have dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu 15.04

When I try to upgrade using Software Updater, it shows that your software is up to date.

I do not want to do it directly using external cd/usb with ubuntu 16.04 image.

UPDATED IMAGE :

[image: Software Updater Upgrade Dialog Box]

After clicking on upgrade button it closes and nothing happens.

Comment: 15.04 is not supported for a long time. Do a fresh install of 16.04.

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal window and type in

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Enter your admin password when prompted.

Note, the update and upgrade are to ensure your system is up to date before doing the release upgrade.

If the above doesn't work, ensure `update-manager-core` is installed in terminal with `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`.

Using the GUI, launch `Software Updater` and click on the settings button.

Click on the update tab, it should look like this
[image]

Make sure the option on the bottom is selected as seen in the picture (long-term support version).  Apply changes and check for upgrades again.

Comment: After third command it says : Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

Comment: Try adding a space and ` -d` at the end.  I updated my answer for you to see.

Comment: I did that but still no change

Comment: I'd advise against using the '-d' switch, because that includes releases still in development. Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) has been released, the current dev version would be the in-progress 16.10. If you're not offered to upgrade to Xenial, you should look into which mirror server you're using. Maybe for whatever reason, that mirror isn't updated any more.

Comment: Based on the answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/91821), OP will need to switch repos before a release upgrade will work.

Comment: Updated the answer.  Check your Software Updater settings as well and ensuring `update-manager-core` is indeed installed.