# Upgrading from 15.04 to LTS 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade to LTS 16.04 and not having any luck. I am following this guide on Ask Ubuntu: [How to upgrade my Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830783/how-to-upgrade-my-ubuntu-15-04-to-ubuntu-16-04)

```
mblanco@mblanco-MS-7680:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
[sudo] password for mblanco: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

I think it might have to be associated with the sources I use for updates which are Canonical Partner, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

15.04 is way past its end of life date (Feb 4 2016) so there is no supported upgrade path. You will have to back up your data and do a clean install.

The answers to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) supply some alternate strategies but the simplest thing to do is a clean install.

Comment: Not necessarily, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release . I agree a fresh install is faster and more reliable.